# How to execute some php code when .click() javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to execute a php code (just a couple of for loops, no echos) when the event  .click() in js occurs on a button. Is ajax a must or there are other options available?
// I know the whole server-client story.

Comment: If you know the whole server-client story, then it should be obvious that some sort of AJAX request is necessary.

Comment: php is server language, javascript is client language, you can't run php code from your current webpage if you don't make a connect to server. So Ajax is a solution

Comment: Not "a" solution @Taiki, it's "the" solution!

Comment: @Dorvalla I dont think the OP phrased the question right. [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is not the only way to communicate with the server and initiate a server-side script. ([Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)), [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and so on)

Comment: Although i dont think you'd want to use anything other than AJAX for such a small requirement as a button click

Comment: Sorry, personal experience got the better hand of me, hence my reply! @kidmenot

Answer (score 2):

PHP is executed server side, so yes, ajax is a must

Answer (score 1):

Since AJAX is a blanket term referring to any sort of "call the server without a page reload" technique, it's unavoidable if you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
Yes, ajax is necessary

PHP will always run on your server. You can send the request with your browser and url bar or with javascript, it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is a must. PHP is serverside, Javascript is a clientside action. So either create a button from a form and let it execute an action (requires to reload the page) or use AJAX to avoid the earlier statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use javascript ajax request, there are at least one other option.

You can load an hidden iframe.
Source of iframe can be something like:

```
<iframe src="/myCode.php?par1=1234&par2=abc"></iframe>
```

In this way, you can execute your php code server side.